# How to process webhook result

Tags: webhooks, watson-assistant

I am trying to connect a webhook to the nhs website using ibm cloud functions and then output result to my watson assistant chatbot

```
function main(params) {
    const options = {
        uri: "https://api.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/"+encodeURIComponent(params.query_topic)+"/?url=https://api.eu-gb.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/...",
        json: true
    }
    return rp(options)
    .then(res => {
        return {text : res} 
    }) 
   }
```

the webhook is successful and it passes the parameters to return information from the correct page

I want the result to just show the main body of text not all the tags so starting from "The main symptoms of coronavirus (COVID-19) are:..."

This is the full output(unable to add images)

```
"{"@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "WebPage", "name": "Symptoms of coronavirus", "copyrightHolder": {"name": "Crown Copyright", "@type": "Organization"}, "license": "https://developer.api.nhs.uk/terms", "author": {"url": "https://www.nhs.uk", "logo": "https://www.nhs.uk/nhscwebservices/documents/logo1.jpg", "email": "nhswebsite.servicedesk@nhs.net", "@type": "Organization", "name": "NHS website"}, "about": {"@type": "WebPage", "name": "Symptoms of coronavirus"}, "description": "Find out about the main symptoms of coronavirus (COVID-19) and where to get medical advice if you think you have them.", "url": "https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/symptoms/", "lastReviewed": ["2021-03-04T11:27:00+00:00", "2021-03-18T11:27:00+00:00"], "breadcrumb": {"@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "BreadcrumbList", "itemListElement": [{"@type": "ListItem", "position": 0, "item": {"@id": "https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/", "name": "Health A to Z", "genre": "condition"}}, {"@type": "ListItem", "position": 1, "item": {"@id": "https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/", "name": "Coronavirus (COVID-19)", "genre": "hub"}}, {"@type": "ListItem", "position": 2, "item": {"@id": "https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/symptoms/", "name": "Symptoms of coronavirus", "genre": "guide"}}]}, "genre": "guide", "hasPart": [{"@type": "WebPageElement", "name": "symptoms", "url": "https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/symptoms/#symptoms", "description": "The main symptoms of coronavirus (COVID-19) are a high temperature, a new, continuous cough and a loss or change to your sense of smell or taste.", "text": "<p>The main symptoms of coronavirus (COVID-19) are:</p><ul><li>a high temperature \u2013 this means you feel hot to touch on your chest or back (you do not need to measure your temperature)</li><li>a new, continuous cough \u2013 this means coughing a lot for more than an hour, or 3 or more coughing episodes in 24 hours (if you usually have a cough, it may be worse than usual)</li><li>a loss or change to your sense of smell or taste \u2013 this means you've noticed you cannot smell or taste anything, or things smell or taste different to normal</li></ul><p>If you have any of these symptoms, get a test to check if you have coronavirus and stay at home until you get your result.</p>", "title": ""}], "relatedLink": [{"@type": "LinkRole", "url": "https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/", "name": "Coronavirus (COVID-19)", "linkRelationship": "Navigation", "position": 0}, {"@type": "LinkRole", "url": "https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/symptoms/", "name": "Symptoms of coronavirus", "linkRelationship": "Navigation", "position": 1}, {"@type": "LinkRole", "url": "https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/self-isolation-and-treatment/", "name": "Self-isolation and treating coronavirus symptoms", "linkRelationship": "Navigation", "position": 2}, {"@type": "LinkRole", "url": "https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/testing-and-tracing/", "name": "Testing and tracing for coronavirus", "linkRelationship": "Navigation", "position": 3}, {"@type": "LinkRole", "url": "https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/people-at-higher-risk/", "name": "People at higher risk from coronavirus", "linkRelationship": "Navigation", "position": 4}, {"@type": "LinkRole", "url": "https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/social-distancing/", "name": "Social distancing and changes to everyday life", "linkRelationship": "Navigation", "position": 5}, {"@type": "LinkRole", "url": "https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/research/", "name": "Take part in coronavirus research", "linkRelationship": "Navigation", "position": 6}, {"@type": "LinkRole", "url": "https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/coronavirus-vaccination/", "name": "Coronavirus vaccination", "linkRelationship": "Navigation", "position": 7}, {"@type": "LinkRole", "url": "https://www.nhs.uk/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/long-term-effects-of-coronavirus-long-covid/", "name": "Long-term effects of coronavirus (long COVID)", "linkRelationship": "Navigation", "position": 8}], "mainEntityOfPage": [{"identifier": "0", "name": "section heading", "position": 0, "@type": "WebPageElement", "headline": "", "text": "", "mainEntityOfPage": [{"position": 0, "identifier": "1", "text": "<p>If you have any of the main symptoms of coronavirus (COVID-19), get a test as soon as possible. Stay at home until you get the result.</p><h2><b>Main symptoms</b></h2><p>The main symptoms of coronavirus are:</p><ul><li><b>a high temperature</b> \u2013 this means you feel hot to touch on your chest or back (you do not need to measure your temperature)</li><li><b>a new, continuous cough</b> \u2013 this means coughing a lot for more than an hour, or 3 or more coughing episodes in 24 hours (if you usually have a cough, it may be worse than usual)</li><li><b>a loss or change to your sense of smell or taste</b> \u2013 this means you&#x27;ve noticed you cannot smell or taste anything, or things smell or taste different to normal</li></ul><p>Most people with coronavirus have at least 1 of these symptoms.</p><h2>What to do if you have symptoms</h2><p>If you have any of the main symptoms of coronavirus:</p><ol><li>Get a test to check if you have coronavirus as soon as possible.</li><li>You and anyone you live with should stay at home and not have visitors until you get your test result \u2013 only leave your home to have a test.</li></ol><p>Anyone in your support bubble should also stay at home if you have been in close contact with them since your symptoms started or during the 48 hours before they started.</p>", "@type": "WebPageElement", "name": "markdown"}, {"position": 1, "@type": "WebPageElement", "name": "Find a service", "identifier": "2", "text": "<p><a href=\"https://www.gov.uk/get-coronavirus-test\">Get a test to check if you have coronavirus on GOV.UK</a></p>\n"}, {"position": 3, "@type": "WebPageElement", "name": "urgent", "identifier": "5", "text": "<h2>Use the NHS 111 online coronavirus service if:</h2><div class=\"block-richtext\"><ul><li>you&#x27;re worried about your symptoms</li><li>you&#x27;re not sure what to do</li></ul></div>\n<div class=\"block-action_link\"><div class=\"nhsuk-action-link\">\n  <a class=\"nhsuk-action-link__link\" href=\"https://111.nhs.uk/covid-19/\" >\n    <svg class=\"nhsuk-icon nhsuk-icon__arrow-right-circle\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" viewBox=\"0 0 24 24\" aria-hidden=\"true\">\n      <path d=\"M0 0h24v24H0z\" fill=\"none\"></path>\n      <path d=\"M12 2a10 10 0 0 0-9.95 9h11.64L9.74 7.05a1 1 0 0 1 1.41-1.41l5.66 5.65a1 1 0 0 1 0 1.42l-5.66 5.65a1 1 0 0 1-1.41 0 1 1 0 0 1 0-1.41L13.69 13H2.05A10 10 0 1 0 12 2z\"></path>\n    </svg>\n    <span class=\"nhsuk-action-link__text\">Use the NHS 111 online coronavirus service</span>\n  </a>\n</div>\n</div>\n<div class=\"block-richtext\"><p>Call 111 if you cannot get help online. Do not go to places like a GP surgery, hospital or pharmacy.</p></div>"}]}, {"identifier": "0", "name": "section heading", "position": 1, "@type": "WebPageElement", "headline": "", "text": "", "mainEntityOfPage": [{"position": 0, "@type": "WebPageElement", "name": "Callout", "identifier": "4", "text": "<h2>Babies and children</h2><p>Call 111 if you&#x27;re worried about a baby or child under 5.</p><p>If your child seems very unwell, is getting worse or you think there&#x27;s something seriously wrong, call 999.</p><p>Do not delay getting help if you&#x27;re worried. Trust your instincts.</p><p>Get more advice about <a href=\"/conditions/coronavirus-covid-19/symptoms/coronavirus-in-children/\">coronavirus in children</a>.</p>"}]}], "dateModified": "2021-03-04T20:52:05+00:00"}"
```

I have read through IBM Watson documentation, NHS API documentation and browsed through Stack Overflow, but couldn't find anything to help me.

[image: image of full json output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you displaying the response now? Just $webhook_response_1?

If so, then I think [this documentation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-webhooks) will help.

About half way down there's a table with two columns: condition and response. [See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM1kI.png)

It says that if you make your condition $webhook_response_1 then your response would be something like this: Your words in Spanish: <? $webhook_result_1.translations[0].translation ?>.

Obviously, change the static text to what you're looking for and change the properties to match what your own JSON is returning.

EDIT:

Based on your comments you are trying to display the data with this: `$webhook_result_1.text.mainEntityOfPage[9].text`

However, based on the format of your json you would actually need to use `$webhook_result_1.mainEntityOfPage[0].mainEntityOfPage[0].text`

Comment: yes i am using $webhook_response_1 i have tried $webhook_result_1.text.mainEntityOfPage[9].text but the way my results are formatted it doesnt give me the desired response i think i need to modify the code in the cloud function to return the result in the desired format,but cannot find anything to explain the code and how to change it everything i found just provided code with no explanation

Comment: The JSON that you posted isn't complete. Can you post the entire JSON that's being returned? It may be best to grab it from directly going to  the URL of your function.

Comment: edited the post and added link to the full json being returned

Comment: It's difficult to work off the image but I'm not seeing a text or mainEntityOfPage key anywhere. I think this may be your issue. I know it's long but can you please include the whole json result in text along with exactly which part of it you're trying to get to?

Comment: added the full output now i basically want all the the text with the information so from "If you have any of the main symptoms of coronavirus (COVID-19), get a test as soon as possible. Stay at home until you get the result...."  and the rest of the text do not want things like "@context": "http://schema.org" appreciate your patience and your effort to help me, thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the json. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked exactly the way I wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the posting above, currently you perform your request to the nhs web site, receive a response as a json payload, then return the complete response back to the Watson Assistant web hook. If you only require a sub element of the returned payload, you need either to extract that element via your cloud function and return this sub element. Or you can within Watson Assistant only "display" within the dialog bode the sub element, i.e. If you return the response to variable $webhook_result_1, then as show above you only use in the node $webhook_result_1.description (the json elements are not clear from above, so you may need to adjust to be correct). Its easier to manipulate the returned json within your cloud function, then within assistant.